# How to get DateListPlot Epilog to display shapes

Tags: plotting, graphics, date-and-time

The following should produced a plot with an orange outlined disc labelled "A" on the dotted line. `Epilog` produces the dotted line and the text label but is unable to produce the disc.

```
data = {{{2006, 10, 1}, 10}, {{2006, 10, 15}, 12}, {{2006, 10, 30}, 15}, 
        {{2006, 11, 20}, 20}};

DateListPlot[data, 
 Epilog -> {
   {Gray, Dashing[Tiny], InfiniteLine[{{2006, 11, 2}, 0}, {0, 1}]},
   {White, EdgeForm[Orange], Disk[{{2006, 11, 2}, 10}]}, 
   {Orange,  Inset["A", {{2006, 11, 2}, 10}]}}
]
```

[image]

Instead of a white disc outlined in orange it is showing an orange line. I have specified the x-coordinate with a date as directed by `DateListPlot`'s documentation.  It also does not work for `Circle`; but I need `Disk` in any case.

Is this a bug or am I doing something incorrectly?

10.3 Win 7 Pro 64 bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your behavior is caused by the fact that the actual scales on the two axes are wildly different. This honestly seems bad design or at least an unintended consequence.

Using your definitions, consider the following:

```
PlotRange@DateListPlot[data]

(* Out: {{3.36865*10^9, 3.37297*10^9}, {0., 20.}} *)
```

The horizontal axis ranges over the billion units, whereas the ordinate only over a few tens of units. When you specify your `Disk` without specifying the radius, the program draws a disk with unit radius. A 1-unit radius is well visible on the vertical axis, but it is extremely compressed on the horizontal axis and appears like a straight line, because of the extreme difference in ranges.

An approach is to **indicate a** `Scaled` **radius**; we need **different scaled values in the two directions** to counteract the effect of the default non-square aspect ratio setting (which defaults to `1/GoldenRatio`) and still get a round circle:

```
DateListPlot[data,
 Epilog -> {
   {Gray, Dashing[Tiny], 
    InfiniteLine[{{2006, 11, 2}, 0}, {0, 1}]}, {White, 
    EdgeForm[Orange], Disk[{{2006, 11, 2}, 10}, Scaled[{0.05, 0.05 GoldenRatio}]]},
   {Orange, Inset["A", {{2006, 11, 2}, 10}]}
  }
]
```

[image: scaled]

I exaggerated the radius here to make it more easily visible; you will want to adjust the `Scaled` directive within `Disk` to suit your taste.

Comment: Seems like the big number is due to date converted to `AbsoluteTime`, i.e. seconds since January 1, 1900: `DateString[3.36865*10^9]` is `Sun 1 Oct 2006 00:06:40`, the first data point.

Comment: Oh, the ellipse form of `Disk`.  I was trying different values for the circle form. No wonder it didn't work. Nice bit with `Scaled` as and, indirectly, `AspectRatio`.  I'll let this sit for a bit just in case.